# OData queries give 404 error unless I add a trailing slash

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, odata

I created a dummy project to test Odata in VS2015 and I was having an exactly the same issue as described in this question, and my code is largely equivalent to what is described there. 
[Web API 2: OData 4: Actions returning 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071517/web-api-2-odata-4-actions-returning-404)

Any query to a bound function gives a 404 error until you add a trailing slash. For example:

http://localhost:46092/odata/v1/Trips/Default.GetTripNameById - 404
http://localhost:46092/odata/v1/Trips/Default.GetTripNameById/ - works as expected

http://localhost:46092/odata/v1/Trips/Default.GetTripNameById(tripID=1)?$select=Name - 404
http://localhost:46092/odata/v1/Trips/Default.GetTripNameById(tripID=1)/?$select=Name - works as expected

This is not supposed to happen because Microsoft documentation never mentions that a trailing slash is required, their examples are supposed to work without them. Also, this breaks the Swagger UI which doesn't add a trailing slash and gets 404 when trying to make any query.

What could be the reason for this behaviour? How do I make it work without a slash, which seems to be the normal expected behaviour?

Here are my code snippets:

TripsController.cs:

```
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTripNameById(int tripID)
    {
        return Ok(DemoDataSources.Instance.Trips.AsQueryable().Where(t => t.ID == tripID.ToString()));
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/v1", GetEdmModel());

DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Person>("People");
        builder.EntitySet<Trip>("Trips");

        builder.EntityType<Trip>().Collection.Function("GetTripNameById").Returns<string>().Parameter<int>("tripID");

        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        return edmModel;
    }
```

Comment: I've also tried all web.config configuration options from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis - and it didn't have any effect. I was adding them into web.debug.config in my VS2015 project.

Comment: web.debug.config is the wrong place (as you note in your answer below). As you probably know now, it's only used when you deploy your project and your publishing settings are set to deploy the 'Debug' configuration of your solution. For localhost development, only what you see in the main web.config is utilized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the Web.debug.config is actually ignored by Visual Studio.

After adding this code to web.config, everything works:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <!-- the following line is required for correct handling of dots in URLs-->
  <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0"
     path="/odata/*"
     verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <!-- end line for handling of dots-->
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```